# Adding several input boxes based by a select box value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select box:

```
<select id="steps_number">
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
```

Now, if the user selects "4", then 4 input boxes needed to be added to the page, if he changes his selection to 8, 8 input boxes need to be there, an so on...

And also, the input boxes names are important, I'm gonna send the form values to another page for processing and inserting the data into db, how I could know/get the newly made input boxes names?

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Nothing actually, I have no idea how jQuery/Javascript works :(

Comment: @behz4d: Time to read a book I'd say, this is no wonder-machine you put in your requirements and get the code back. [Do your homework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice).

Comment: @behz4d start reading [JavaScript guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide) then read [How does jQuery work](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very simple example (also [demonstrated here](http://jsfiddle.net/FFfRT/1/)):

```
// bind to when the drop-down list changes
$('#steps_number').change(function(){    
    // find out the number to display
    var count = $(this).val();

    // Try to keep the fields already on the page. Remove anything
    // that exceeds the count
    $('#steps input:gt('+(count-1)+')').remove();

    // But if it doesn't have enough, add more
    for (var i = $('#steps input').length; i < count; i++){
        $('<input>',{type:'text',id:'step'+(i+1),name='step'+(i+1)}).appendTo('#steps');
    }
});
```

This assumes you want the following structure for your inputs:

```
<div id="steps">
  <input type="text" id="step1" name="step1" />
  <input type="text" id="step2" name="step2" />
  <input type="text" id="step3" name="step3" />
  <!-- .... -->
</div>
```

And with regards to server-side, you'll now see the inputs using `$_REQUEST['step1']`, `$_REQUEST['step2']`, etc. Or, depending on your form method, they'll show up in `$_POST` or `$_GET` as well.

Comment: @behz4d: No problem. I've tried to comment the code to give you an explanation, but if you have any questions post a comment to this answer and I'll do my best to review it.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote for you some basic functionality. But you need to extend it for your needs:

```
$('#steps_number')​.change(function(){
    for(var i=0; i < parseInt($(this).val()); i++) {
        $('body').append('<input type="text" name="someinput' + i + '">');
    }
});​
```

See on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/antyrat/ZsKj6/)

Comment: 1. Given the webmaster is supplying the values of the `<select>` is `parseInt` necessary? 2. You're going to keep adding more and more controls to the page. I'd recommend either a wrapper you can reset and re-populate, or a check for previous elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>

    <script language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){

            alert("ok");
            $("#steps_number").change(function() { 
                var inputNum = $("#steps_number").val();

                var inputCode = "";
                for(i=0; i<inputNum; i++) { 
                    inputCode += "<p class=\"inputBox\"><input id=\"inputBox_" + i + "\" size=\"20\" type=\"text\"></p>"
                }

                $("#inputBoxes").html(inputCode);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <form id="testform">
        <select id="steps_number">
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
        </select>

        <div id="inputBoxes">

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
<select id="steps_number">
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
</select>
<div id="container"></div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#steps_number").on("change", function() {
    var count = $(this).val()
    $("#container").html("")
    for (i=0;i<count;i++) {
        $("<input>").appendTo("#container");
        $("<br>").appendTo("#container")
    }
})

</script>
```